# Why did I get temporary ban for editing questions?

Tags: support, edits, edit-ban

I was trying to edit some questions and got a message saying that I have been temporarily banned for editing. Why did that happen and for how long will this ban last?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

8 out of the 13 suggested edits you have done have been rejected, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3789676/ballpython?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)

So you must have ran into the automatic ban threshold by having too many rejected edits and not enough approved ones. The message you got tells you how long the ban will be.

Please review the rejected edits on that paged I linked to, and when you are able to edit again, please try to fix all the issues in the post, and make sure tag edits are really necessary. It seems that many reviewers did not think a lot of your tag edits were necessary.

Do note that only review bans and account suspensions can be manual and are applied in severe cases of not improving after receiving automatic bans.

Comment: Edit bans are always automatic. Only review bans, and entire account suspensions, can be manual.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but link leads me to my profile

Comment: @BallPython Yes it does. Look where it says either "approved edit" or "rejected edit" , for each suggested edit. Click on the rejected ones, and read why they were rejected.

Comment: got it, the only thing i wanted to know, how long this ban lasts?

Comment: @BallPython: The message you received tells you exactly this.

Comment: but how many days he would have been banned?

Comment: @BoltClock fyi : `edit-ban` can also be manual..i was banned from editing questions manually by a mod..http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/a/1942/27149

Comment: @Lucky: FYI, this wasn't true at the time of this discussion.

Comment: It seems that the edit ban duration is no longer included in the message.