# You are temporarily banned from suggesting edits

Tags: support, edits

In last [23 suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5602744/spylh9999ggr?tab=activity&sort=suggestions&page=1), only 2 of my edits are rejected, but I am facing

> You are temporarily banned from suggesting edits

I saw these kind of questions are answered before, but those users had lot of rejected edits.

Comment: I could be a manual ban applied by a moderator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did I get temporary ban for editing questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280175/why-did-i-get-temporary-ban-for-editing-questions) and [Editing Ban, But Few Rejected Edits?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299808/editing-ban-but-few-rejected-edits/299814#299814).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ seems you are right.